# glGetHistogram WebGL / C++

Tags: javascript, c++, opengl, webgl, histogram

I am trying to implement the [glGetHistogram](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetHistogram.xml) method in WebGL (Google Chrome 16.0.912.63).

So far I've the following code in my method that draws the canvas:

```
  var histogram;
  gl.enable(gl.HISTOGRAM);
  gl.getHistogram(gl.HISTOGRAM, gl.FALSE, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, histogram);
  gl.disable(gl.HISTOGRAM);
```

I always get

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<WebGLRenderingContext> has no method 'getHistogram'
```

- Is there actually no implementation of glGetHistogram in WebGL or am I missing something here?
- Maybe you could also share some C++ code as I am trying to get glGetHistogram to work in C++ as well.

Cheers!

Comment: is it available now by any chance? Or is there any alternate solution? I have been struggling from many months for the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebGL is based on OpenGL ES 2.0, and the documentation you linked is for Desktop OpenGL 2.x, so you're looking at the wrong documentation.

And yes, there's no glHistogram in WebGL.

Comment: is it available now by any chance? Or is there any alternate solution? I have been struggling from many months for the same